# Html table withsubsections

Tags: html

I want to create table with main section and subsections like that[image: target table]

I tried

```
<html> 
<body>
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
   <td rowspan="3">section</td>
   <td rowspan="3">subsection1</td>
   <td rowspan="2">subsection1</td>
   <td rowspan="1">subsection1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>text1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>text2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>text3</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

but this code dont create dont create subsections. Surrounding  subsection1 with  also dont create subsections.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rowspan` attribute indicates the number of rows a cell should take up. There are 6 rows total in your table, so if you want a cell to span to the last row of the table, you specify `rowspan="6"`. Note that the `rowspan` values should sum up to the same number for each column, the default value being 1.

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="6">section</td>
    <td rowspan="3">subsection1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">subsection2</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1">subsection3</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0Ly1eok/)

Comment: i was so close yet so far